# Four Dead outlets

Tags: electrical

My granddaughter just moved into an new (old) house and four outlets have no power.  I checked for any power and there is none using an outlet tester.  No indication at all.  How do I find the circuit breaker for that circuit?  I have a tester but it takes power for that to identify which circuit is connected to which breaker.

Comment: Might be easy and it is the breaker that is tripped is the one you are looking for.  If not, then turning off the main breaker will work for checking the outlets safely, just in case they are on different breakers.

Comment: First, find the breaker panel or fuse box.  (Note that in homes built prior to about 1960 there may be several panels.)  Turn each breaker off and then back on.  (Sometimes it's hard to see that a given breaker is in "tripped" mode.)  For old-fashioned twist-in fuses, unscrew each fuse about a half-turn, then screw it back in.  While doing all this note if any breaker or fuse seems "strange", then come back and examine those more closely if the off/on step doesn't fix things.

Comment: If these are four outlets in four different rooms, check to be sure they are not each controlled by a wall switch, e.g., for use with a table lamp.

Comment: Check all your breakers to make sure they are all seating tight and are on.  Furthermore check the outlets themselves by removing the cover plate.  See if they are connected and test the wires directly.  Find out which one of them is the lead receptacle feeding the other three and test its wires directly and if they are part of the same circuit.  The last receptacle will only have two wires going to it.

Comment: Check for any GFCI outlets that might have tripped.